# How to get membership related information by using YoutubeDataAPI

Tags: youtube-data-api

I want to use the Youtube API to determine if a video is membership-only or not.
I tried to find out the actual video information using YoutubeAPI's videos, channels, playlists, etc., but it doesn't seem to contain any information related to membership.
Is there any good idea?

Comment: Can you share us a video id which is membership-only please ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Some membership video ids are Ln9yZDtfcWg, FBeSuH5I5M4.

Answer (score 1):

One more time [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) doesn't provide a basic feature.

I would suggest you to use my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/0f1f4281cbd3f70eca2d0c7feffc61089c5c01d5#diff-515c409ddb619da28c52829262e517f3d2ab4910aaa2ab60dd88e9064e0cfd4fR170-R172) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com), indeed by requesting https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=isMemberOnly&id=VIDEO_ID you would get a JSON with the boolean value interesting you in `item['isMemberOnly']`.