# How to tell if a YouTube video is live for use YouTube Data API

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I can judge whether this video is live by judging whether there is liveStreamingDetails in the collected data.

```
if 'liveStreamingDetails' in video_data:
    video_type = 'live'
```

But doing so will treat the premiere video as a live broadcast.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a way to distinguish whether a video is live or premiered.

I refer to the answer from [Use beautifulsoup to get a youtube video‘s information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402280/use-beautifulsoup-to-get-a-youtube-video-s-information).

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

video_url = "YouTube Url"
session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get(video_url)
response.html.render(sleep=3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.html, "lxml")

if soup.select_one('#info-strings').text[:8] == 'Streamed':
    video_type = 'live'
else:
    video_type = 'video'
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I tested, [the liveStreamingDetails:concurrentViewers entry](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers) is missing for premiere videos being broadcasted. So you can check, using for instance [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list), if this entry is part of the response to know whether or not the video is a livestream being broadcasted or a premiere being broadcasted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But liveStreamingDetails:concurrentViewers is also missing from live streams that have ended. The videos I identify are those that have ended live or premiered

Comment: From what I've investigated, the YouTube Data API doesn't seem to be able to do this. So I'm thinking whether I can directly find the source code of the web page. See <yt-formatted-string class="style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer"> followed by "Streamed live" or "Premiered".

Comment: It seems that you can distinguish an ended livestream and an ended premiere by using [`status.uploadStatus`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.uploadStatus) obtained with https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=VIDEO_ID&key=API_KEY For the livestream it should be `uploaded` and `processed` for the premiere. Respectively ids to test with [`TCBbXgBIC1I`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCBbXgBIC1I) and [`2aamcJeIvEg`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aamcJeIvEg).

Comment: According to the example you gave, there is indeed a difference, but I use "qzRRvb8v8mE" and "-r2OqPvJDwM" to test, both give "processed" results

Comment: You are right [`qzRRvb8v8mE`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzRRvb8v8mE) and [`-r2OqPvJDwM`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-r2OqPvJDwM) don't have such difference... I think using a parsing of source code is the best thing to do, as I did in my [open-source YouTube operational API](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API) with the `isPremiumOnly` for [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72167620/how-to-get-membership-related-information-by-using-youtubedataapi). If you could share your solution in my API it would be really appreciated.

Comment: I managed to solve this problem, but I'm sorry I can't provide a solution for your project, I only know how to write Python. I hope my approach can provide you with some ideas.

Comment: Thanks anyway for sharing your working solution! By the way, as I have done in my open-source API, if you want to optimize your algorithm by not executing JavaScript, I think in `ytInitialData` JS variable encoding JSON data when fetching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID there is an entry distinguishing an ended livestream and an ended premiere.